# Deploying laravel app: bash: line 1: /heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, web-hosting

I deployed my laravel project to a webhosting Heroku, but it says: `Application error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command heroku logs --tail`

Running in cmd `heroku logs --tail` shows:

```
023-02-11T12:34:54.553423+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-02-11T12:34:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-02-11T12:34:57.640287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`
2023-02-11T12:34:58.531590+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: line 1: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory
2023-02-11T12:34:58.712929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-02-11T12:34:58.762310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-02-11T12:34:58.765815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-02-11T12:35:01.791169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`
2023-02-11T12:35:02.654080+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: line 1: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2: No such file or directory
2023-02-11T12:35:02.826744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-02-11T12:35:02.880557+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2023-02-11T12:35:35.602534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=poradej-turnaj.herokuapp.com request_id=ace405c4-8cd9-46f0-8f22-fd7f47ac3fb4 fwd="84.42.219.107" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-02-11T12:35:35.773667+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=poradej-turnaj.herokuapp.com request_id=01ba20cd-82bf-45c8-ab60-0e61295ed805 fwd="84.42.219.107" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is some of my code, which I think could be related to this problem:
Procfile
`web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 public/`

Composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.19",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.7",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.0",
        "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php" : "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }, 
        "files":[
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Can you give me please any advice? Tell me if you would like some more code. I know that this problem has been already discused here but none of the advices helped me.

Answer (score 0):

`heroku-php-apache2` is [provided by Heroku's PHP buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#web-servers), not Composer.

Edit your `Procfile` to remove `$(composer config bin-dir)/`:

```
web: heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Then commit and redeploy.